# Freemarker applying join after another join

Tags: java, freemarker

I got such a data:

```
{ "key1" : [ "value1", "value2" ],
  "key2" : [ "value3", "value4" ],
  "key3" : [ "value5", "value6" ] }
```

And i want to create sql query `WHERE` clause from them like this:

```
WHERE
column1 in (value1, value2)
OR
column2 in (value3, value4)
OR
column3 in (value5, value6)
```

I try to make an assign `<#assign column1 = <#if key1??> ${key1?join(", ")} </#if> >`, but it seems that it is not possible

The question is: how to set `OR` delimiter between clauses? How to apply join from join? Maybe some else solutions without using assign?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use can use `#list`, and `#sep`. Something like this:

```
WHERE
<#list map as k, v>
${k} in (${v?join(", ")})
<#sep>
OR
</#list>
```

Also, you might want to use `?join` in simpler cases instead, like I did above for the nested listing. If that listing has to do something complicated, you you probably want to use `<#list v as it>complex stuff for ${it}<#sep>, </#list>` there.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be taking values from data and putting them directly into the sql as this will make your application susceptible to [sql injection attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Please see https://xkcd.com/327/

[image: bobby tables]

Instead, you should be creating sql like

```sql
WHERE column1 in (?, ?)
OR column2 in (?, ?)
OR column3 in (?, ?)
```

Then doing something like

```java
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setString(1, data.key1[0]);
ps.setString(2, data.key1[1]);
...
ps.setString(6, data.key3[1]);
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
while (rs.next()) {
   ...
}
```